Preserving Styles in google translation API
I'm attempting to translate formatted text (Rich Text) using Google Translate while retaining styles like Bold, Italic, Underline, and Links. I've tried using both embedding tags and  elements, but the styles aren't maintained.

Rich text-structure
When using style specific tags, google translate discards the tag in some cases which cause an exception.
On other hand, using span and inline styles, its impossible to nest the styles.
